# How to iterate CTE result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT MemberGroupID 
    FROM [dbo].[RoleMembers] WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE RoleDefID = 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Above query works fine in my stored procedure. But it will return many rows so I want to iterate all the rows and use `MemberGroupID` to call another stored procedure.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use for loop and user the query

Comment: i dont want to use cursor or for loop.I want to implement using CTE

Comment: What does the SP do?  Can it be a TVF?

Comment: A recursive cte is also a loop... You may want to rewrite yout ptocedure to accept a table valued parameter instead of using loops.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti : no it is not TVF its SP. i want to iterate cte value and want to use that value to call another SP to get result

Comment: If you want to call the other SP for each MemberGroupID you cannot do that in the CTE but only with a loop.

Comment: What does th stored-procedure return? You could fill a temp table and then join this with the the CTE. Or you could replace the SP with a table-valued-function(or scalar-valued-function) which you can call from a query.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it will return true or false

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia: then make it a scalar valued function instead which you can call from the query

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  If your SP can be a TVF, you can use the results in a CROSS APPLY

Comment: @JohnCappelletti no it cant be a TVF.. its SP which is created by other developer

Comment: 1) Scalar/Table Function 2) SP that supports Table Valued Parameter 3) loop 4) dynamic sql that expands loop into many consecutive calls. _"to iterate cte value and call another SP"_ - this is a **cursor** description.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti : can you please provide some guidance how can i use TVF with cross apply

Answer (score 3):

As requested, and not knowing what your SP does/return:

Think of a CROSS APPLY like a sub-routine

**Example 1:**

```
Select A.MemberGroupID 
      ,B.*
 From  [dbo].[RoleMembers] A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe](1, A.MemberGroupID )  B
 WHERE RoleDefID = 1
```

**Example 2:**

The following will split and unpivot a delimited string by ID

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, Value varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'New York;Albany;Providence'),
(2,'Atlanta;Kinderhook')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Value,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       New York
1   2       Albany
1   3       Providence
2   1       Atlanta
2   2       Kinderhook
```

Comment: Jhon my tvf returns BIT value

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia Example 2 was to demonstrate that you can have queries within the CROSS APPLY and return a single or multiple records/values

Comment: @jhon i am getting error "Invalid object name 'dbo.fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe'." and when i simple call function i.e Select dbo.fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe (1, 6) it will return proper result

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia can you call the function on its own   Select * from dbo.fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe(anyPrameters)

Comment: @jhon : yes...I have call the function like "Select dbo.fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe (1, 6)" and it provides proper result

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia see updated Example 1  .. assuming the second parameter is MemberGroupID

Comment: @jhon yeh i am doing the same way but still i am getting the same error

Comment: @jhon : Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Select B.*, A.MemberGroupID
From  [dbo].[RoleMembers] A
CROSS APPLY (Select db =  dbo.fn_GroupMembers_HasMembershipe(A.MemberGroupID,6))  B
WHERE RoleDefID = 1
```

this the way to use Cross Apply in sqlserver 2014

Comment: So function is NOT a Table Valued Function, but a Scalar Valued Function.  The Cross APPLY would not be necessary

Comment: @jhon is it possible i can get value one by one so that i can apply filter or any logic on that. What i have to do is i will send MemberGroupID and my function return 'true' or 'false'.if it returns false then i will send another MemberGroupID or if it returns true then i will break it and return true. is it possible without cursor?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and provide some sample data and/or a use case.  This may or may not require a CURSOR.